# virtual address space in a variable partition scheme

Tags: operating-system, virtual-address-space

I know this question  is more on OS than on programming,sorry for that.
In a multiprogrammig scheme with variable partitions
who has to decide the size of a process virtual address space??
what if during execution we find out a process needs more memory??

With variable partition scheme I mean a scheme that does not involve segmentation or paging
but countigous allocation.

Comment: A process' virtual address space is fixed on a machine which has access to segmentation. Every process has access to the same virtual address space, and used pages are mapped to whatever physical addresses. This question does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something without Virtual Memory? Systems without MMU give a fixed space to each process, even the maximum stack size is encoded in the binary file format, see the bFLT format for an example.